# Correct way of maintaining array structure in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indexing

Let's say I declare a 3d array in R:

```
arr <- array(rep(0, 20), c(1,2,20))
```

We I call `arr[,,1]`, I'd get

```
[1] 0 0
```

I would expect a 1-by-2 matrix instead of a vector like above

By adding `drop` to it, like `arr[,,1, drop=F]`, I'd get

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

This is not ideal either, because it's not a matrix. It leads to error when being used in matrix multiplication.

I could wrap it with `matrix()` like `matrix(arr[,,1, drop=F])` and get

```
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
```

Then the dimension would be wrong. Finally I do `matrix(arr[,,1, drop=F], dim(arr)[1:2])`, and it gives me the correct result.

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
```

Of course if the dimensions of the 3d array are all greater than 1, then it wouldn't be a problem at all. **My question is if there's a simpler way of getting a matrix when subsetting a 3d array, in any circumstances.**

Comment: You can assign the dim instead of calling the `matrix`.  `'dim<-'(arr[, , 1], dim(arr)[1:2])`  It seems to be more compact

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot. Mind explaining what it does or why it would work?

Comment: I posted as a solution with some explanations

Comment: @akrun Seems that you updated your comments already. It still seems a little bit awkward, considering many other languages don't have similar problems. And when coming to generalization, it would be cumbersome to make it work for `arr[1,,]`, let along array of 4d, 5d, etc... Is this supposed to be an intrinsic problem of R?

Comment: @42- `is.matrix(arr[,,1, drop=F])` gives `FALSE`. Similarly if you call `t(arr[,,1, drop=F])` R would throw an error `argument is not a matrix`

Comment: Sorry. `arr[,,1, drop=F]` is an array. In most instance the matrix structure would be as you expect, but when one of the dimensions is 1, it gets simplified to a vector. But I guess you have seen that.

Comment: @42- Thanks for your comment and I agree. The problem is when it comes to matrix multiplication etc, this kind of simplification could lead to a lot of complications, right? I thought R should already have solved this problem but I haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: @WillGu I can't see the complications you are talking about, so guess you should provide a little more context. It's very peculiar that one has a multiple dimensions array where some dimensions are long 1. Remember also that R can't read your mind: if you subset an array which has a lot of dimensions with length one, it can guess which one to drop.

Comment: I don't see the problem. `[` is documented to return a vector in this case. How is it supposed to know you want a matrix and what matrix dimensions (n*1 or 1*n) you'd like? Simply use `matrix` with the `ncol` and `nrow` parameters to turn the vector into a matrix.

Comment: @nicola and @Roland Thank you both for your comments. I found answer in another post and thought `abind` is the way to go. I guess the "complication" I was talking about comes from the fact that R tries to simplify things but sometimes it's not what the user might want, e.g. the default `drop` argument is all-or-nothing which is probably not flexible enough. And I feel that when calling `arr[,,1]`, intuitively I'd expect a 2d array unless otherwise specified, no? At least that's true for most of the other languages that I use.

Comment: @WillGu: Agree with you that one might have expected `arr[,,1] to deliver a 2d matrix, at least I did and I've been using R for 8 years regularly and have read the help page for ?'[' at least 10-20 times. Thanks for the question and if anybody is still reading this exchange I encourage them to upvote the linked duplicate. (My searching didn't find it.)